# What is the size I should create for Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, drawable, android-screen-support

My device's logical resolution is `480x800` and density is `mdpi`, I want to have a background image occupy half of the screen, which is logically `240x400`, so what image I should create in photoshop and put under the `drawable-mdpi` folder?

My understanding is if my image was created in desktop with `72 dpi`, then I should prepare my image as ..

```
w = (240 * 160 / 72) = 533
h = (400 * 160 / 72) = 888
```

So I should prepare an image in photoshop using the size of 533x888 (72dpi) and put under the `drawable-mdpi` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the approach you outline but you could also put a high-resolution image in the `res/drawable` folder and set the width and height in the layout files with device independent pixels (`dip` or `dp`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/my_image_description"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
```

Of course the scaling of the images can hurt the overall quality but you might also encounter other `mdpi` devices that have a different resolution and thus the image will be scaled anyhow.